# S3 - delayed method registration in R

Tags: r, import, package

I have an R-package ('[mill](https://github.com/SVA-SE/mill/tree/dev)') with a 'suggest' ('[hlt](https://github.com/trosendal/hlt)') where I would like to register a new class for an S3 method in 'hlt'. Because the 'hlt' package is a suggest I followed the advise of Hadley and copied a function in 'mill' that registers my new `mill::html.pdf_diff_df()` function but not until after loading the 'hlt' package:

https://github.com/r-lib/vctrs/blob/master/R/register-s3.R

The problem I encounter is that when I load 'mill' and call the `html()` method on the new class ('pdf_diff_df') defined in the 'mill' package I just get the error:

```
html(df)
Error in html(df) : could not find function "html"
```

I would, of course, like to give the warning that one should load the 'hlt' package at that point, otherwise the user doesn't understand the problem. Any ideas? The source in 'mill' of this new function is here:

https://github.com/SVA-SE/mill/blob/136f372f88d794bb6149922c24dd9a4f731e4c7e/R/images.R#L195-L206

Comment: This might be useful: https://vctrs.r-lib.org/reference/s3_register.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, `hlt` exports `html()`, but you don't want a fixed dependency on `hlt`, so you can't import `html` from `hlt`.

In that case, simply use a fully qualified call to it, i.e. `hlt::html(...)`.
Since `hlt` is only in `Suggests`, this should only be called conditional on `requireNamespace('hlt')` returning `TRUE`.

**Edited to add**:
If you want a user to be able to call `html(...)`, you have to export it from your package.  This is hard, because it is exported from the `hlt` package, and if the two packages export different versions, you'll get warnings about one hiding the other.

As far as I know there isn't a nice solution to this, but really, it's not your problem.  If a user hasn't attached `hlt`, they have no reason to expect `html(...)` to do anything.  If they have, it will just work.

If you really want to help out the user without generating new messages, you could export your own function with a different name, something like

```
html2 <- function(...) {
  if (requireNamespace("hlt"))
    hlt::html(...)
  else
    warning("Suggested package 'hlt' must be installed for this to work.")
}
```

Comment: Not quite... the `hlt` package implements the S3 method `html()`. I want to register a function for this `hlt::html()` method in the `mill` package for a new class in mill `pdf_diff_df`. If I imported `hlt` this would just work, but since I include it only as a suggest; It doesn't work until I load `hlt`. When I call `html` from mill I want to give a `warning("please load ''hlt")` now I'm just getting "could not find function 'html'"

Comment: I think you're confused about R jargon.  S3 methods always have the form `generic.class`.  `html()` looks like a generic, not a method.  (It could also be a plain old function, you can't tell the difference between non-S3 functions and generics by the name.) The method for class `pdf_diff_df` would be `html.pdf_diff_df` for the generic `html`.  But since you can't import `html`, when you call it, R gives you the "could not find function" message.  Use the fully qualified call.  Generate the warning if `requireNamespace('hlt')` returns `FALSE` (but it should say "please install").

Comment: Thanks! As I was typing my comment I was actually realizing that my understanding of the nomenclature was a little weak :)